# Include url parameter in url path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

`products_path(page: 1)` generates url `/products?page=1`.

How to generate `/products/page/1` instead?

Assuming I have

```
resources :products
```

in `routes.rb`.

Comment: I page a model?  I ask this as I would like to know why you seem to be breaking the RESFUL conventions?

Comment: @MarkStratmann, url parameters are ignored by page caching and this workaround was suggested in rails caching guide (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#page-caching).

Answer (score 1):

Add this to routes.rb:

```
match "/products/page/:page" => "products#index"
```

It will set the page parameter in the params hash.

Comment: Thank you for response at first, I was asking about slightly different thing though, about generating URL from view or controller which would look like `products/page/1`.